# How do i make a horizontal bar with a logo on the left

Tags: html, css

i'm currently programming my own website, and i'm having a problem with the navigation bar. I'm trying to make a small navigation bar with my logo on the left and the hyperlinks on the right, but no matter what i did the results were either the logo was misplaced and the hyperlinks were on top of the logo or the logo was placed where i wanted it to but the hyperlinks weren't. Thanks in advance.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#000000;
}
p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul{
    color:#ffffff;
}
#topbar{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #242424;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#tb_hyperlink{
    display:inline;
    left:0;
  }
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
  }
li{
    display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  }
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  }  

#space{
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="topbar">         > 
 <div id="tb_logo">
<a href="https://acrazytown.com">
    <img src="logo_small.png"/>
        </a>   
        <ul id="tb_hyperlink">  
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/my-projects">MY PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/news/">NEWS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://status.acrazytown.com/">STATUS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: "horizontal vertical bar" is a contradiction.

Comment: i typed that accidentally

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking since **we don't know what this is supposed to look like**.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code for doing this with different code of css

I have commented some code use which you prefer the best use width with this as well.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#000000;
}
p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul{
    color:#ffffff;
}
#topbar{
    background-color: #242424;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
li{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size:14px;
  }
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block
  }  
div#tb_logo {
    height: 50px;
}
#space{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Style 1 Using Flex*/
#topbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

/*Style 2 
#tb_logo, #tb_hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
}
*/

/*Style 3 
div#tb_logo {
    float: left;
}
#tb_hyperlink {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="topbar"> 
      <div id="tb_logo">
        <a href="https://acrazytown.com">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" title="Logo" />
        </a>
      </div>   
      <ul id="tb_hyperlink">  
                <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="space">|</li>
                <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/my-projects">MY PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li class="space">|</li>
                <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/news/">NEWS</a></li>
                <li class="space">|</li>
                <li><a href="https://status.acrazytown.com/">STATUS</a></li>
                <li class="space">|</li>
                <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
     

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You control classes with a `.class` and ids with a `#id`.
Change `#space` to `.space` and it looks like this:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#000000;
}

p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul{
    color:#ffffff;
}

#topbar{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #242424;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#tb_hyperlink{
    display:inline;
    left:0;
}

ul{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
}

li{
    display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}  

.space{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
 <div id="tb_logo">
    <a href="https://acrazytown.com">
      <img src="logo_small.png"/>
    </a>   
    <ul id="tb_hyperlink">  
      <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="space">|</li>
      <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/my-projects">MY PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li class="space">|</li>
      <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/news/">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="space">|</li>
      <li><a href="https://status.acrazytown.com/">STATUS</a></li>
      <li class="space">|</li>
      <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also please try to do yourself and others a favor by formatting your code in a good looking way. Don't just throw random tabs and spaces in front of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="topbar">
 <ul id="tb_hyperlink">  
            <a href="https://acrazytown.com">
    <img src="logo_small.png">
   </a><li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/my-projects">MY PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/news/">NEWS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://status.acrazytown.com/">STATUS</a></li>
            <li class="space">|</li>
            <li><a href="https://acrazytown.com/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

CSS

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#000000;
}
p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul{
    color:#ffffff;
}
#topbar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: 
    #242424;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#tb_hyperlink{
    display:inline;
    left:0;
  }
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;

}
li {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  }  

#space{
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```